# Finding a correlation or statistically significant relationship in data

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance

I have a data set that is represented below, but much longer.  How can I find if there is a statistical relationship between business category and business score?

```
Business Name     Business Category        Business Score
Business1         Shopping                      1
Business2         Eating                        1
Business3         Shopping                      2
Business4         Shopping                      2
Business5         Eating                        1
Business6         Manicure                      3
Business7         Haircut                       2
Business8         Haircut                       3
Business9         Eating                        3
Business10        Manicure                      3
Business11        Haircut                       3
Business12        Eating                        1
Business13        Shopping                      2
Business14        Eating                        3
Business15        Manicure                      1
Business16        Haircut                       3
Business17        Haircut                       2
Business18        Shopping                      3
Business19        Eating                        2
Business20        Manicure                      3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that business is categorical, you can't use correlation.

Business score looks like it is a 1-5 rating or something like that. If that is the case, I would recommend ordinal logistic regression In `SAS` use `PROC LOGISTIC`. In `R` there is `polr`. The dependent variable would be "score" and the independent variable "type of business".

Comment: The OP appears to use the term "correlation" in the nontechnical sense of a "relationship." A constructive way to interpret that is that it's a request to identify *significant differences* in score among business categories.

Comment: Hi, I guess I should not have used the term correlation.  I am only looking for a significant relationship between business category and business score.  Does the above answer still satisfy this?

Comment: Yes it does. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: @PeterFlom I believe so?  I imported the arm package and the data and did this: `x <- polr(Business.Category ~ Score, data = data)`.  Then I did `summary(x)` and got this output, http://pastebin.com/sBGg1xEG, although I'm not really sure what to make of it.

Comment: @PeterFlom Also, are there any other descriptive statistics I can show on x that would show a significant relationship, maybe p-value or r-squared?

Comment: Ordinal logistic should give a p-value.  There is no exact equivalent to $R^2$

Comment: @PeterFlom So, in the pastebin link above, the results of the regression give me `Coefficients: Score 0.2945238`.  Is that the p-value?

Comment: The link did not work for me. The coefficients are not p values; looking at ?polr I see it does not give p values; it does give t values and confint(model) gives confidence intervals. I am not sure why it doesn't give p values. `SAS` does give p values for similar methods

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try a simple Chi-square test. Make a frequency table of "Business Category" vs "Business Score" and then go for a chi square test. I don't have R in this PC. Later I will post some code.